# Doctrine fulltext on multiple field

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I've got an entity with some attributes and I want to index some of them for fulltext.

```
* @Index(name="search", columns={"description", "short_description", "name"}, flags={"fulltext"})})
```

Now if I execute a query using `MATCH(description, short_description) AGAINST (...)` I get:

> Can't find FULLTEXT index matching the column list

If I index for fulltext only one column:

```
 * @Index(columns={"description"}, flags={"fulltext"})})
```

And then try to use MATCH(description) AGAINST (...) all works right.
So how can I index multiple columns?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution to my question, so i post it for someone who will have the same problem.
I index three columns doing :

```
* @Index(name="search", columns={"description", "short_description", "name"}, flags={"fulltext"})})
```

So i have to use all of it in my query :

```
MATCH(description, short_description, name) AGAINST (...)
```

I can't match only some of these index.
Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to insert multiple indexes in the indexes property.

```
/**
 * @Entity
 * @Table(name="table",indexes={@index(name="foo_index", columns={"foo"}),@index(name="bar_index", columns={"bar"})})
 */
```

Note that Doctrine2 ORM does not support `MATCH AGAINST` and performance of full text searches become really bad, if even possible in some cases.

When having many requests and performance is important you should have a look at Lucene based search servers such as Elasticsearch or Apache Solr.

Comment: In this way i can't do : MATCH(foo, bar) AGAINST (...) as I asked. I can only  do MATCH(foo) AGAINST (...) , MATCH(bar) AGAINST (...)